# Service Fabric Refresh Application debug mode - The filename or extension is too long

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to use the new **Refresh Application debug mode** for Service Fabric but I am getting a deployment error "The filename or extension is too long".

I have tried both Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 Preview 3 with the same error.

Debugging with the "Remove application" mode works with no issues.

I have Service Fabric SDK 2.6.204 and 2.5.216 installed.

Any idea how to find out which file is too long and why would this happen only for refresh mode?

Comment: How many nodes do you use?

Comment: this is deploying to the local cluster in a 1node configuration.

Comment: Sounds like a potential bug, or at the very least, a usability problem. Can you create a GitHub issue so we can track it here: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/

Comment: We're running into this issue as well. My team and I are looking into alternative deployment and debugging flows to help solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a limitation in the tooling and PowerShell, and how the debug engine publishes to the Service Fabric cluster. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/933). There's no known workaround at this time.